# Angular.Module with[] is not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs. The following is working:

```
var kk = angular.module('app').factory('VendorService', Service);
```

The following is not working:

```
var kk = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']).factory('VendorService', Service);
```

Can anyone help me? thanks a ton!

Comment: what error does it show? import error?

Comment: If I add any more injection, the run function in main module is not working.

Comment: how do you know it's not working? does it show you an error?

Comment: In run function I have alert(). Alert is working when I have only ['ui.router'] and not when I add more.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your code in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I have copied code to collabedit: http://collabedit.com/bgh2j

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164881/discussion-between-chintu-and-omar-einea).

Answer (score 0):

Injecting external dependencies is required on main Angular module declaration.

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

When declaring a new controler/resource/factory or other, you don't have to inject external dependencies.

```
angular.module('yourApp').factory('Service', Service);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Here is the main Angular Module declaration: `angular
        .module('app', ['ui.router'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);` If I add anything more like ['ui.router','ngResource'] the run function is not working.

Comment: I installed ngresource but no luck :(